# Probability: finding variance of $Z=\frac{X^2}{Y}$

Tags: probability

I have $X\sim\mathrm{Uni}[0,3]$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{Uni}[0,5]$. Let $Z=\ln\left(\frac{X^2}{Y}\right)$. What is $\mathrm{Var}(Z)$?

I assume I have to use the simulation for random variable with exponential distribuion.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $Z = \ln(X^2) - \ln(Y)$.  Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so are $Z_1 = \ln(X^2)$ and $Z_2 = \ln(Y)$, so $\text{Var}(Z) = \text{Var}(Z_1) + \text{Var}(Z_2)$.